# Do achievements/awards give any reward?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In World of Tanks, you receive rewards, accolades, achievements, etc during games where you perform well.
For example, you will earn Top Gun if you get at least 6 kills in a single game.

My question is do these rewards give you any boost in XP/credits, or are they simple "ego-boosters"?

if there is a chart/database somewhere on how much these awards actually earn you(seeing as there is quite a bit)... that'd be great too (I couldn't find one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in most cases these awards give you no other reward than looking nice on your profile. So they are in effect "ego-boosters"

One important exception is that sometimes Wargaming has events where achieving an award during a battle will give you an immediate bonus. (For example a top gun reward getting you 50,000 credits). However, these special events happen infrequently and the reward you get for an award is not known until Wargaming makes the announcement which usually happens a few days before the event.